# How to boot windows after uninstalling ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, boot, windows-8, multi-boot, uefi

I am using windows 8 system and I tried to install ubuntu by making a separate partion. But after deleting the partitions created for Ubuntu, it is still trying to load ubuntu and not windows.

If I load ubuntu using live cd, I can see all windows files present on the disk. How to point drivers to load windows?

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The majority of new computers that ship with Windows 8 are EFI-based. On such a computer, you need to restore the Windows boot loader to be the primary one and/or delete GRUB from the EFI System Partition (ESP). You can set the Windows boot loader to be the primary one in various ways, but unfortunately, they all take a lot of explaining and/or are tricky to do. Deleting GRUB from the ESP is relatively easy to explain, so I'll do that:

1. Boot a Linux live CD.
2. Identify your ESP by typing sudo parted /dev/sda print and locating the partition with the "boot flag" set.
3. Mount the ESP by typing sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt (substituting the correct device identifier for /dev/sda).
4. Type sudo rm -r /mnt/EFI/ubuntu to remove Ubuntu's version of GRUB. If you've manually installed GRUB somewhere else, remove it instead of or in addition to Ubuntu's GRUB.
5. Reboot.

When you reboot with GRUB absent, the computer will bypass that no-longer-functional entry and use the next one in its list, which should be the Windows boot loader.

A caveat: If you've used Boot Repair, you may need to re-run it and use its advanced options to undo its renaming operations. If you fail to do this, you'll end up still running your non-functional GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by @Premjith is ok, if you want a simpler solution:

- boot your computer from the windows 8 dvd
- launch the "startup repair"; it should identify your windows installation and recreate boot data.

It basically does the same thing: mark the correct partition as bootable and recreate (if needed) mbr data