# deleted linux mint from windows 8 dual boot reinstalled linux can't make it work

Tags: linux, boot, windows-8.1, grub, linux-mint

I have a lenovo g710 laptop with windows 8.1 preinstalled.I made a dual boot with linux mint and everything was ok.Then i did something in linux terminal and when i restarted the pc linux wouldn't load and stick to the lm logo.I decided to delete linux and reinstall it.From windows i removed linux partition restarted the laptop but grub was there (grub > not grub rescue >).First i  tried from windows cd in cmd /bootrec /fixboot,then in a new boot /bootrec /fixboot+/bootrec fixmbr still nothing. As a solution i found this 
  [How to boot windows after uninstalling ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/681379/how-to-boot-windows-after-uninstalling-ubuntu)

then pc boots normally in windows 8.1. After that i created a new partiotion from windows disk management to reinstall mint.Booted live cd saw  the installation programm didn't see the windows partition but i procceded to linux installation with something else option and created /,/home and swap area.After the completion of install i was asked to continue trying mint from cd or restart pc.I chose restart a black screen appeared saying welcome to linux mint and then an error apperared something with monitordesktop i don't remember it excactly and restart stuck there.I pressed continuously power button to shut down.At the next restart gnu grub was there and i had the option to choose windows or linux.I booted in windows,but in the next restart grub was not there and pc booted to windows.My next move was to boot linux live cd and mount the boot partition to see its contents so i did cd /dev/sda2 and with it i saw the folders one of them was ubuntu but i couldn't acess it for example with ls command giving me the input/output error.

Also when i boot the live cd the first thing to appear before grub is could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallvack.efi" :14

The windows are pre-installed with efi (i saw it from disk management) and for every boot i use the novo button go to boot menu where windows appear first and the my live cd.

I really need to find a solution and get linux to work.Sorry for writing extremely too much but i wanted to give the whole problem.

Thank you for your time reading this!